# How to fix header but not footer with flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

What I tried is:

```
import Header from 'components/layouts/Header';
import Footer from 'components/layouts/Footer';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

type Props = {
    className?: string;
};

const PageLayout: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, className }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-full bg-gray-100">
                <Header />
                <div
                    className={`flex-1 overflow-y-auto page-wrapper ${className}`}
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};

export default PageLayout;
```

The result is this.

[image]

I got two scroll bars on the right side, which is strange.
How can I achieve having the header fixed but not footer with flexbox? Or is there any easier way to fix the header only?

Comment: I think you need to change this `overflow-y-auto` to something else like overflow hidden

Comment: Seems to be the inner components has fixed height and overflow property

Comment: No it's not a good practice, setting overflow hidden will hide the overflowed items. Make sure `height:auto`

Comment: `min-height:0` on the main div might help. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys for the discussion! None of them worked for me, but I might have tried your ideas in wrong way.

>Ragul Cs, Where should I put `height:auto`? I replaced `h-screen` with it in the main div.

> G-Cyrillus, `min-height:0` instead of `h-screen`? Or need to put them both?